# write a shell script prgram to reverse the order of content of existing file and give it as input to other file

Tags: unix

I have one already existing file with content and  I have to reverse the order of that file for example 
mango
tomato 
and output should be
tomato
mango
and the output should be input to new file.

Comment: Please add some code to sow what have you tried so far

Comment: foreach name ($argv)
if ( -f $textFile ) then
 echo -n "reverse the file '${textFile}' {y/n)?
endif
set ans = $<
switch ($ans)
case n:
exit
case y:
tac textFile.txt > Rev
continue
endsw
end